# asp.net mvc application forms browser forward and back button not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a mvc  application. Here i have show three menu[Customer,Salesorder and Invoice] and   create a CommonController and one ActionResult Index() [Index.cshtml with Jquery]. then three menu forms data list loaded dynamically . when i click customer or Salesorder or Invoice then load data same index page working fine.

First i click Customer form, show customer list then second i click Salesorder form showing, Salesorder list and then i click Invoice form, showing Invoice List. Now am going to Browser Back and forward button click means Invoice List only showing.

[image: Browser image]

But i want, when i Browser back button click one by one going to previous form. For example Invoice form list back to Salesorder form list and back to Customer form list. like forward button.

sorry for i did written bad english..

Please undestand my questions and help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you want to be able to navigate forwards and backwards when looking at a page, the browser buttons should work on a normal day, but this is also achievable using HTML.

e.g

```html
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="history.go(-1)">Go Back</a>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: your answer is separate view page[Customer.cshtml,SalesOrder.cshtml, Invoice.cshtml and etc] is working perfectly. But commonly used [Index.cshtml] not working]. I have create one Index.Cshtml[ 3 forms loaded this one Index.cshtml]. thanks for your answer [you did understand my questions]

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution for browser back and forward button click event javascript condition. Please check it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.performance.navigation ==2)
{
alert("Back and Forward button clicked !");
}
</scrip>
```